# How to load elements in Heroku Static Web HTML Hosting?

Tags: css, heroku

I just started doing web development, and using bootstrap from here:

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/

I changed around some padding, font, elements, etc, but overall, I kept to the same format as from the bootstrap code.
Everything looks good locally (running index.html) but I want to host it. But since my application isn't ruby or php web app that Heroku supports, I tried to do a hack I read about by making an index.php and composer.json and pushing my code to Heroku.

Everything seems to be pushed fine to Heroku, but when I check my Heroku app, it looks like a mess, the nav bar is "invisible" to the top left and unclickable (checked location with Firefox console) and some formatting is off.

How do I get the elements to load properly?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku isn't really designed to do static hosting. I downloaded the bootstrap code and tested it and the nav bar and bootstrap elements are missing for the most part.

With that said I believe that Heroku is having troubles loading certain css/ scss resources that need to be preloaded, you may need to convert the entire project or try using a script to make gulp work in composer.json and editing your procfile to different host since I assume you are using default heroku-php-apache2.

Comment: I am using the default heroku-php-apache2 because I didn't have a procfile, but I don't think it's a problem with the gulp install? It doesn't give me any errors in the command prompt when I deploy to heroku master